# angularjs ui-router - How can I hide the submenu when a specific child-route was hit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on an AngularJS / Ui-router example where I have the following:

[image: Music state]

A state news, with a sub-state music, when clicking on music the news active state is maintained because I have **news.music** (music a sub-state of news).

However, sports state is not a sub-state of news. How can I maintain news active state (blue background) when I click on sports?

[image: Sports state]

I have seen many related posts but they are so old.

Here are snaps of the code:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('news', {
    url: '/news',
    templateUrl : 'news.html'
  })
});

app.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('sports', {
    url: '/sports',
    templateUrl : 'sports.html'
  })
});

app.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider.state('news.music', {
    url: '/music',
    templateUrl : 'music.html'
  })
});
```

**index.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="news">News</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**news.html**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="sports">Sports</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="news.music">Music</a></li>
</ul>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

And a running [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/977k9YTjIkqYDQcU0n4J?p=preview)

Comment: I love you questions Eddy :) You designed your application in a way where "sports" is a subview (views) of news. Your routing provided that sports is not a subview of news ...  but you also want to make the menu option "news" active when sports is clicked. Your view structure does not match to your route configuration.

Comment: @lin Your contribution is appreciated. Exactly, I am just simplifying the case I have in a real app. Somehow, I don't want to show the sub menu when entering the sub-state, so I don't use **news.sports** but I want to maintain **news** active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while this is still a error in your application design you could do it with a controller by having `news.sports` as a child route of `news` like in this [runnable plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sbxpn4GTrlYZ1po10eSa?p=preview). Your questions should be: "How can I hide the submenu when a specific child-route was hit".

#### View

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-controller="submenuController" ng-show="showSubMenu">
  <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="news.sports">Sports</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="news.music">Music</a></li>
</ul>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

#### Controller

```
app.controller('submenuController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state) {

  $scope.showSubMenu = true;

  $scope.$watch(function(){
      return $state.$current.name
  }, function(currentStateName){
     $scope.showSubMenu = currentStateName === 'news.sports' ? false : true;
  }) 
});
```